# How do I make postfix rewrite the to address to contain multiple recipients?

Tags: postfix

I am trying to set up Postfix to re-write the destination of emails sent to `example@myhost` to instead appear to have been sent to `example1@example.com` and `example2@example.com`.  I am using LDAP lookups to tie this into FreeIPA, using the email addresses tied to user accounts.

The relevant lines (I think) from my `main.cf` file (redacted to replace real domains with "`example.com`" and IPs with `192.0.2.0/24`):

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, proxy:ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf
masquerade_domains = myhost.example.com, example.com
mydestination = $myhostname, myhost.example.com, example.com, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
myhostname = myhost.example.com
mynetworks = 192.0.2.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
relayhost = [otherhost.example.com]
smtp_generic_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-generic.cf
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-generic.cf
```

`ldap-aliases.cf`:

```
server_host = ldaps://ipa1.example.com
search_base = cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=example,dc=com
query_filter = (&(uid=%u)(mail=*))
result_attribute = mail
bind = yes
bind_dn = uid=postfix,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=example,dc=com
bind_pw = example_password
version = 3
```

`ldap-generic.cf` is the same as `ldap-aliases.cf`, with the addition of the line:

```
domain = myhost.example.com, example.com
```

So far, it seems that email sent to the `example@myhost.example.com` address goes to `example1@example.com` and `example2@example.com`, but only has a `To:` header stating `example1@example.com`.  I would like it to show all addresses, not just the first.

Answer (score 0):

The `alias_maps` alone only modifies the envelope recipients without tampering the headers. Take a look at [To rewrite message headers or not, or to label as invalid](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#william) on Postfix Address Rewriting README.

> Postfix versions 2.1 and earlier always rewrite message header
>   addresses, and append Postfix's own domain information to addresses
>   that Postfix considers incomplete. While rewriting message header
>   addresses is OK for mail with a local origin, it is undesirable for
>   remote mail.
>
> Postfix versions 2.2 give you the option to either not rewrite message
>   headers from remote SMTP clients at all, or to label incomplete
>   addresses in such message headers as invalid.

Comment: I understand that, which is why I also have the `smtp_generic_maps` option, but that only uses the first email in the alias.